# Problem with Create Function statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, create-function

I am attempting to create a function in MySQL that will return a value based on the presence of specific strings in a field.  My select statement will ultimately need to make this evaluation many times so I wanted to create a function for efficiency purposes.  Here is my code:

```
create function [dbname].id_datasource
(descval varchar(100))
returns varchar(10)  
begin  
        declare datasource varchar(10) default ''  
        select datasource =   
            case when descval like 'CLT%' or descval like '%CLT%' then 'CLT'  
            when descval like 'PCB%' or descval like '%PCB%' then 'PCB'  
            else 'NA' end   
        return (datasource)  
end
```

I get this error:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select datasource =
> case when descval like 'CLT%' or descval like '%CLT%' th' at line 6

note:  it requires me to enter a db name prefix for my function - it returns 'no database selected' without it - I did substitute my long database name for [dbname] above.

Comment: You need `;` at the end of statements in a stored procedure or function.

Comment: Variable assignments use `SET`, not `SELECT`.

Comment: Side note: When `descval like '%CLT%'` is true, so is `descval like 'CLT%'`, `descval like 'CLT%'` is therefore redundant. Same for `descval like 'PCB%'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax problems:

1. Missing `;` at the end of each statement.
2. Use `SET` to assign a variable.

```
DELIMITER $$

create function [dbname].id_datasource (descval varchar(100))
returns varchar(10)
begin  
        declare datasource varchar(10) default '';
        SET datasource =   
            case 
                when descval like '%CLT%' then 'CLT'  
                when descval like '%PCB%' then 'PCB'  
                else 'NA' 
            end; 
        return datasource;
end
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

There's no need to have both `LIKE 'CLT%'` and `LIKE '%CLT%'`, since anything that matches `CLT%` will also match `%CLT%`.

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking on CLT% vs %CLT% - thanks.  On the query itself, I still get an error - just at an earlier spot:  SQL Error [1064] [42000]:     You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.id_datasource (descval varchar(100))

returns varchar(10)

begin  

        dec' at line 1

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the way you entered the database name before the function name.

Comment: You nailed it.  I was including database and specific table.  That worked.  Thanks much.

Comment: BTW, you can set the default database using `USE databasename;`